# Having Trouble Understanding How To Use Singleton Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I've been trying to code something so that:

Class 1 creates an instance of Class 2 (Class t = new Class() ). That instance can be used in Class 1,2 and 3.
I've been looking around for a bit and found the "Singleton Pattern". I don't understand how I implement this into my code though and a fair few of the sources are all saying different things...

Thanks for any help, much appreciated :)

Comment: How does Class 3 relate to classes 1 and 2?

Comment: Give it a try, post the code and we can help you from there. Do you understand what the purpose of the Singleton pattern is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Singleton Example:** If you have a Class Phonebook and you want every Class of your programm refer to the same Phonebook. You would make the Class Phonebook a Singleton-Class.

**In other words:** The Singleton Pattern is used, to asure every other Code is refering to the same Object of the Singleton-Class.

```
class Phonebook {
    //Make the constructor private so no one can create objects, but this class
    private Phonebook() {
    }
    // to static members to hold (m_Instance) and get (getInstacnce) the Singleton Instance of the class
    private static Phonebook m_Instance;
    public static Phonebook getInstance() {
        if (m_Instance == null) {
            // first call to getInstance, creates the Singelton Instance, only we (Phonebook) can call the constructor;
            m_Instance = new Phonebook(); 
        }
        return m_Instance; //always the same Instance of Phonebook
    }
    ... // Members of the Phonebook (add/getPhoneNumber)
}
```

Every part of the software, will get the same Instance of the Phonebook. So we can register phonenumbers, every other class can read.

```
...
Phonebook l_Phonebook = Phonebook.getInstance();
l_Phonebook.addPhoneNumber("Yoschi", "01774448882")
... 
// somewhere else
Phonebook l_Phonebook = Phonebook.getInstance();
Phone.getInstance().call(l_Phonebook.getPhoneNumber("Yoschi"));
```

Comment: In a multi-threaded environment the creation must be synchronized. See the double-checked locking design pattern.

Comment: Yes! Your right. But I didn't want everything getting to complicated at once.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the description:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

A sample code will be

```
public class singleton
   {
       public static singleton _obj;
       private singleton()
       {
           // prevents instantiation from external entities
       }
       public static singleton GetObject() // instead of creating new operator, declare a method and that will create object and return it.
       {
           if (_obj == null) //Checking if the instance is null, then it will create new one and return it 
           //otherwise it will return previous one.
           {
               _obj = new singleton();
           }
           return _obj;
       }
       public void printing(string s)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(s);
       }
   }
```

This is a c# code but the concepts are the same as java.